# Zoninator zone manager plugin - get and set zones programmatically

Tags: plugins

I'd like to use the excellent [Zoninator plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/zoninator/) with my theme, making it a required plugin using the [TGM Plugin Activation Class](https://github.com/thomasgriffin/TGM-Plugin-Activation/). On activation of the plugin I want to create one or more zones programmatically. Can anyone tell me how to

- Set a listener in my theme which performs a function when a particular plugin is activated
- Create a specific Zoninator zone in that function, if it doesn't already exist?

For the first part I've tried this in my functions.php:

```
register_activation_hook( plugins_url('zoninator/zoninator.php', __FILE__), 'myplugin_activate' );

function myplugin_activate() {
    //
}
```

But nothing happens when I activate Zoninator.

For the second part I've tried calling z_get_zones() to see what Zoninator zones already exist. But I get warnings like "Attempt to assign property of non-object in [..]\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\zoninator\zoninator.php on line 1129", and a WP error object that reports "Invalid taxonomy".

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As advised by the Zoninator developer Mohammad Jangda, you can solve the second part of this problem like this:

```
    if (z_get_zone(‘home’) == ”) {
        global $zoninator;
        $zoninator->insert_zone( ‘home’, ‘Home’, array(‘description’ => ‘This is the Home Zone programmatically inserted’));
}
```